# How to find revision ID of a Git repository without cloning in GITHUB

Tags: git, github, egit, github-api, jgit

By means of cloning I am able to find the HEAD of a git repository and using HEAD I can find the revision ID in GITHUB using following code in Egit:-
ObjectId revId = repository.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
How can I find this revision ID without cloning the whole repository by only knowing the url of my GITHub repository as cloning the whole repository takes time.Pls suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From any directory, you can use [`git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote):

```
C:\Users\VonC\>git ls-remote https://github.com/git/git master

e230c568c4b9a991e3175e5f65171a566fd8e39c        refs/heads/master
4b5eac7f03f411f75087e0b6db23caa999624304        refs/remotes/github/master
4b5eac7f03f411f75087e0b6db23caa999624304        refs/remotes/origin/master

C:\Users\VonC\>git ls-remote https://github.com/git/git HEAD
e230c568c4b9a991e3175e5f65171a566fd8e39c        HEAD
4b5eac7f03f411f75087e0b6db23caa999624304        refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

You can see that way the SHA1 of the refspecs including the ref you are interesting in.
The examples above list the SHA1 of refspecs including '`master`' or '`HEAD`'

You can see the `HEAD` of the repo 'git' is 4b5eac7... and it corresponds to `heads/master` (which means the HEAD of that remote repo is the `master` branch)

No cloning was needed for that command to work.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about the commit hash?

You can easily see it on the "Commits" page.

Example for AutoFixture: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/commits/master

As you can see, each commit has its hash on the right hand side. The hash for the HEAD of master is `cdc59a9a4889504d882aaa47b222a0410174d917`. For `HEAD^` it is `ab05261e1d175d93f11ed37020f802933a20789c` and so on.

Comment: No this is the list of all the commits done.I only wanted to know the revision ID of my own repository without cloning.Is that possible?

Comment: @Alok: There is no such thing as a revision ID. Please clarify what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

You could get this information from the GitHub API.

The API provides [an endpoint to get all commits for a repository](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository). In your case,
you can just fetch the most recent commit on the branch in question. For
example, this curl request fetches the most recent commit from the `master`
branch of the `rails/rails` repository.

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails/commits?sha=master&per_page=1"

[
  {
    "sha": "c52a4ae565671e3a3b1513a285dc887102d5eb15",
    "commit": {
      "author": {
        "name": "Santiago Pastorino",
        "email": "santiago@wyeworks.com",
        "date": "2013-09-03T15:18:41Z"
      },
      "committer": {
        "name": "Santiago Pastorino",
        "email": "santiago@wyeworks.com",
        "date": "2013-09-03T15:18:41Z"
      },
      "message": "Revert \"Merge pull request #12085 from valk/master\"\n\nThis reverts commit 15455d76c8d33b3767a61e0cdd2de0ff592098ef, reversing\nchanges made to ffa56f73d5ae98fe0b8b6dd2ca6f0dffac9d9217.",
      // ...
  }
]
```

In this example, we see that `c52a4ae565671e3a3b1513a285dc887102d5eb15` is the most recent commit. Note that we see the same info in the web UI:

[image: Most recent commits on the master branch of rails/rails]

Comment: Sounds good. +1. The only advantages of my solution is that it lists only the HEADS SHA1 (instead of all the commits), and works for any upstream repo (instead of just GitHub repos).